# Transaction reverted during simulation

Tags: anchor, transactions, phantom

I am working on a dapp, and running a transaction to transfer some usdc from one wallet to another wallet, when tested on devnet it is working smoothly but when I am testing it on mainnet it is showing this warning on phantom wallet "Transaction reverted during simulation"

Comment: This just means your transaction is probably going to fail if sent, but there are many reasons that might happen. Most wallets don't give much information for this. You might be able to get some more information if you look at dev tools for the wallet, or if you call the `simulateTransaction` RPC (or using web3js) yourself. You could also send the transaction (make sure you're using a burner in case your tx does something unexpected) and then look at on-chain logs when it fails, to debug what the error is.